# Calculate the expectation of random variable, integration of a function.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

I want to calculate the expectation of one random variable $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$, where $x\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $a$ is a constant.

It is straightforward that we can come to the integration of the following
$$\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} dx.$$

How can we handle this integration, or how can we approximate its value?

Comment: This is a modified Bessel function in terms of the quantity $\eta = a^2/(2\sigma)^2$, which has a nice series expansion about $\eta = \infty$, so it would have good approximation properties when $a/\sigma$ is large.

Comment: Thanks!  What is the general form of the modified Bessel function you mentioned?